# How to get into an active docker container?

Tags: docker

I've ssh'd into the production box where my docker containers where  and was able to list them with `docker ps`.
I got a list of containers that looked like:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                 CREATED         STATUS         PORTS              NAMES
123456789012   postgres:9.5   "docker-entrypoint..."  6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   1234/tcp           post
rails1234567   rails_image    "/usr/bin/docker-e..."  23 hours ago    Up 23 hours    0.0.0.0:4000/tcp   rails_auto
```

I was trying to get into the rails_image using commands:
`docker exec -it rails_image bash`
`docker exec -it rails_auto bash`
`docker exec -it rails1234567 bash`

They are failing with error:
`rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that bash wasn't installed in the docker container.
The correct command was:

`docker exec -it rails1234567 sh`

This worked because `sh` was installed in the container.

Comment: `sh` will always be installed.